# Using R, how can I create an .RTF file containing a table with a merged cell?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, rtf

I need to create an `rtf` file with a "complexe" table inside (in fact I just need horizontal merged cell).

I tried the `{RTF}` package, but the `addTable` function takes a data.frame or table object without any parameter like colspan ..

I tried to use Rmarkdown with `rtf_document` output, but Rmarkdown doesnt support merged cell (`kableExtra`, create an html object to do so)

I know how to create a `docx` with this kind of table (using `{officer}` and `{flextable}`) so maybe it could be a good solution to convert a `.docx` file into `.RTF` .. any idea how to do this? (or maybe latex -> RTF ?)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Cells that span multiple columns or rows of a table are not supported by `pandoc` (see [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables) and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/aibux0lO8yM)).

In the `rtf` package, there is an internal function `rtf:::.add.merged.table.row()`. It produces `rtf` code for an horizontally merged row. But maybe you would want to write your own function.

Below, an example of a `rtf` code for a one-row table:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\cellx1000
\cellx2000
\cellx3000
\intbl cell 1\cell
\intbl cell 2\cell
\intbl cell 3\cell
\row
}
```

You can save these lines to a `rtf` or `doc` file to see the rendered table.

Following the [`rtf` spec](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/obsolete/info/RTF/RTF-Spec.rtf), horizontally merged cells are defined using `\clmgf` and `\clmrg`. Here's the same table with a second line with first two cells merged:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\cellx1000
\cellx2000
\cellx3000
\intbl cell 1\cell
\intbl cell 2\cell
\intbl cell 3\cell
\row
\trowd
\clmgf\cellx1000
\clmrg\cellx2000
\cellx3000
\intbl cell 1\cell
\cell
\intbl cell 3\cell
\row
}
```

However, producing native `rtf` is an horrible task.

Therefore, I think your best option is (as you suggest) produce a `docx` or a `latex` file and post-process it to `rtf`. There's a [`latex2rtf`](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) library but it comes with a great disclaimer:

> In fact, don't expect any LaTeX file to be converted as you would like, don't expect it to be converted without errors or warnings, and don't be especially surprised when it doesn't convert at all. LaTeX2RTF is known to have many bugs and many missing features. Paradoxically, this number seems to grow more and more with each day. However, we can categorically state that there are some special cases in which a LaTeX file will be translated to RTF satisfactorily by LaTeX2RTF

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create a table in a RTF document with R. I used the RDCOMClient. I have been able to merge two cells of the table in the RTF document with the following code.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\empty_RTF_File.rtf"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
content <- wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$Content()
table <- wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$Tables()$Add(content, NumRows = 3, NumColumns = 4)

for(i in 1 : 3)
{
  for(j in 1 : 4)
  {
    table$Cell(i, j)$Range()$InsertAfter(paste0("i ", i, " j ", j))    
  }
}

obj_Border <- table$Borders()
obj_Border[["InsideLineStyle"]] <- TRUE
obj_Border[["OutsideLineStyle"]] <- TRUE

table$Cell(1, 1)$Merge(MergeTo = table$Cell(1, 2))
```